# Is there a hidden background in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, backgrounds

I have a beamer presentation for which I want to put a picture as a background for all slides. In order to do so, I use the `eso-pic` package with the command `\AddToShipoutPicture`.

My problem is that there seems to be a white layer on top of my background image. I cannot find a way to remove this layer. On the first slide, the white layer is evidenced as shifting its content of 2cm on the left, partially reveals the image background I have... After commenting one after another all the options and packages of my presentation, I reach the minimalistic code below that still contains the undesired white layer !

Is there any option to remove this layer ? I cannot see what is wrong with my code.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPicture{\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=15cm]{images/fond_poly.pdf}}} 
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\setlength{\hoffset}{-2cm}
\makeatother
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image: white layer on top of my background image]

Comment: off topic: observe in the pdf properties that the dimensions of the pdf created by beamer is very small. So, 15cm is too large.

Comment: I do not think the size of the image is the issue here, even a smaller image yields the same result. I enlarged it because at some point, I was wondering where it was...

Comment: Yes, this is why I wrote *off topic*.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found my answer... the following line needs to be added in the preamble: `\usebackgroundtemplate{}`:

```
\documentclass[nobackground]{beamer}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usebackgroundtemplate{}

\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPicture{\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=15cm]{fond_poly.pdf}}} 
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\setlength{\hoffset}{-2cm}
\makeatother
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

which then gives the expected result.

[image: solution !]